# React - is it more secure if you validate forms on client or server?

Tags: reactjs, security

In react, is it better to have form validation checks such as if email is proper or not on client or on server? Wouldn't it be more faster on client, but less secure. For example, let's say you have a login form with react. In the login form, you could have two fields: an email field and a password field. Let's also say you wanted to check if the email was a valid email. Would it be more efficient and secure to do this check on the server and make the server reply to the client or the client just handles all kind of checks like that. Or perhaps would it be best to do the checks on both client and server?

Comment: Most of the things done by the client is UX, most of security is enforced on the server. There are exceptions, but as a rule of thumb.

Comment: Never trust the client.  You have no control over what is connecting to your server- selenium automation, cURL, most any programming language can act like a browser.   They also can send data outside the range in your HTML + script, like a price of -100. The reason you do client-side checks is for the user experience, to keep them from skipping a field or accidentally entering bad data.  So: you do both, on the client for UX and on the server to make sure everything is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as validations are concerned, it is always advisable that they are carried out both on the client and on the server as the APIs are public, therefore anyone can make calls. As far as the client is concerned, it is correct to add validations to avoid overloading the server with useless calls and to reduce traffic. The thing I recommend is to have an API to retrieve the validation regexes and then use them both on the client and on the server.

Comment: A good idea with sharing the validation code if practical.